# Not able to use firstIndex:where in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift

I am getting `Incorrect argument label in call (have 'where:', expected 'of:')` error when I use `firstIndex` on an array of dictionary.

```
let d: [NSMutableDictionary] = [["u": 1], ["u": 2], ["u": 3]]

let i = d.firstIndex(where: { dict -> Bool in
    return dict["u"] == 2
})
```

[image: incorrect arg label]

Why is this occurring and how to fix this?

Comment: You should not be using NSMutableDictionary. This is Swift! Use Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has no way of knowing whether `== 2` can work with `dict["u"]`. *You* know that `dict["u"]` is an Int, but *Swift* doesn't know that, because by typing these dictionaries as NSMutableDictionary you have hidden the types of the values.

To fix that, change `[NSMutableDictionary]` to `[[String:Int]]`.